# Cargar un Smart select desde un javascript

Tags: javascript, phonegap, framework7

Estoy trabajando con `Framework7 v4` en `PhoneGap` y quiero cargar un `Smart Select` desde un javascript

Este es mi `HTML`

```
<a class="item-link smart-select smart-select-init" data-open-in="popover">
 <select name="superhero" id="gender" >
 <option value="Batman" selected>Batman</option>
 <option value="Superman">Superman</option>
 <option value="Hulk">Hulk</option>
 </select>
 <div class="item-content">
 <div class="item-inner">
 <div class="item-title">Titulo</div>
 </div>
 </div>
</a>
```

este es mi javascript

```
function pintarEmpresa(){

    var dato = _db_obtener_dato(); //obtengo desde BBBDD el item para cargar en el smart select
    myApp.smartSelect.create('.smart-select');
    myApp.smartSelect.get('.smart-select').setValue(dato);

}
```

el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

que estoy haciendo mal? alguien puede poner un ejemplo de como hacer eso?

Comment: Tu componente no existe, o al menos cuando js lo busca y quiere acceder a él no lo encuentra.

Comment: y como se crea? En la pagina no de framework7 veo nada

Comment: Intenta pegando esto en la etiqueta a
**data-open-in="popup" data-virtual-list="true" data-page-back-link-text="Go back"**

según la documentación de este link es así

https://framework7.io/docs/smart-select.html